# How to store background colour and text size in local storage in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to allow users of my website to change the colour of the background and change the size of the text if they wish?

Is it possible to store them in local storage and if so, can you provide some html code to allow this?

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show your attempts and where you fail.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript.
HTML web storage provides 2 types of storage:

- Local Storage (No expiration date)
- Session Storage (Data lost if you close the browser)

If you want to, for example, save the background color of your site:

```
localStorage.setItem("bgcolor", "red");
```

Then, when your page is loaded, check if a user changed his background color:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("bgcolor") !== null) {
    document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem("bgcolor");
}
```

More informations: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp